# Calculating probabilities in genetic sequences

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, markov-chains

I am working with certain recurring sequences in genetics and try to calculate certain probabilities:

Let for instance
$$\langle g_i\rangle  :=\{1,1,1,6,1,1,1,6,...,1,1,1,6\}$$ and
$$\langle h_i\rangle  :=\{1,1,1,1,6,1,1,1,1,6,...,1,1,1,1,6\}$$

be to recurrent chains of identical length $i_{\max}=20$

How can one calculate the probability that at a certain selected index $i_*$ we would have on both chains a $1$, i.o.w.:

$$\langle g_{i_*}\rangle =\langle h_{i_*}\rangle =1$$

... to explain further the expansion of the problem...
let $\langle a_{i,m} \rangle$ be $m$ recurring sequences (in above example $m=\{1,2\}$) each with different frequencies of recurrence $f_m$ (above example $f_m=\{4,5\}$) and the identical entrailed length of $L=\prod_{m}f_m$.
How can I calculate the probability that (only) the 1 of all $m$ chains would be compatible?

Comment: TeX tip: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for $\langle$ and $\rangle$. I fixed it for you.

Comment: Are you picking randomly from each array, or picking a single random i value and seeing if those elements match?

Comment: Which aspects of the question concern the tags `(probability)`, `(probability-theory)` and `(markov-chains)` is not clear at the moment. Please explain.

Comment: see below please. I think it well fits to a probability theory problem and I am not sure whether the order in the chains could relate to Markov chains.

Comment: Sorry but there is not an iota of probability in the explanations you gave in a now deleted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are picking a single value i, the arrays are of twenty elements and the pattern is identical to the one you have here, the answer is fairly easy, every fourth and fifth element, if picked will not be a match, there are 20/4= 5 fourth elements, plus 20/5= 4 fifth elements, so 9 pairs that are incompatible. So the probability of a match is (20-9)/20= 55%

Comment: That brings me nearer, but, one of the compatible is a pair $6,6$ instead there are 12 compatibe $1,1$. Your calculation comes right but the way seems bumpy. My problem is that I want to find a general formula. See my answer comming below.